# Repair Automatically Disabled/Greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, content-database, health-analyzer

I'm trying to resolve some issues under monitoring, the main one being "
**Content databases contain orphaned items**". However, the 'repair automatically' is disabled and I don't know how to repair 'manually'. I'm logged onto the server with the domain admin account, the same one that originally installed Sharepoint so should have the necessary permissions. How can I enable the repair button?

I can't find any similar questions. Also, the link mentioned under 'remedy' (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-foundation-2010/ff805076(v=office.14)) just says to click the fix now button.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By default**, the `Repair Automatically` option is disabled for `Content databases contain orphaned items.`.

**To enable the `Automatic Repair`, do the following:**

- Central Administrator > Monitoring > Click on `Review rule definitions`.
- Below `Availability` category > Find the `Content databases contain orphaned items.` > click on it.
- From the above ribbon > click on Edit Item.
- Check `Repair Automatically`.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to run from the following command from powershell

```
(Get-SPContentDatabase).Repair($true)
```

which will give the output -

```
<OrphanedObjects Count="0" />
```